# how to redirect a site in android

Tags: android, http

I want to redirect a site .how it can be done using http ??pls any one explain me?I am new to android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you need something like this...

```
intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "redirect a site" ? If its a redirect of a web site from one url to another then it can be done on the web server - no need for android involvement.....